# pg dump with folder format fails for large database with error : no space left on the device

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, pg-dump

We are running postgresql database server running as docker container inside a VM. Postgresql docker image version is 10. Server size is 32 cpus and 256 GB memory.

VM Specs : Ubuntu 18.04, Docker version : 19.06, Postgresql data of container is mounted to a seperate 2TB disk on the host VM.

I trid to take pg_dump using below command with folder format

```
pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U azuredbadmin -j 18 -Fd proddb -f prod-db-backup
```

The source database size is very big 1.2 TB.

This command is running for 5 hours  and throwing the error with message Pasted below.

```
pg_dump: [directory archiver] could not open output file 'prod-db-backup/blob_36511541.dat': No space left on device
pg_dump: [parallel archiver] a worker process died unexpectedly
```

But we have very big disk of 4TB attached of which the generated dump size is only 250 GB before it fails after running for 5 hours. Since we have still 3.7 TB free space available on the disk, The error is just misleading and we are clueless.

We checked the inodes count as well. It looks fine and also if we re-run the pg_dump command again to the same disk (to different output folder), Its again running for 5 hours and failng again at the same point and same error. The second attempt of pg_dump command also consumed 250 GB and then failed.

We have observed the disk monitoring as well, and it shows the disk consumption is not even reaching 20% (of 4 TB disk) at any time. No peaks observed, which means disk space isn't a problem I believe.

Even the docker data is mounted to another disk on the root Filesystem on host machine which is also 2TB. So the error is really making us clueless. i.e, docker root Filesystem size is 2TB. and it didn't get to near 100% at any time.

I observed one thing, all the 3-attempts resulted in exactly same folder size in bytes.
The folder size in bytes "605876224", which means It is exactly failing at same point on every attempt.

```
ls -ltr

drwx------  2 root root 605876224 Nov  3 12:33 prod-db-backup
drwx------  2 root root 605876224 Nov  4 15:04 prod-db-backup-2
drwx------  2 root root 605876224 Nov  2 10:44 prod-db-backup-3
```

When I run pg dump command with .dump format output instead of folder, It ran successfully and consumed 900 GB. But This method doesn't work for us and our goal is to restore this in another DB server and it took many days to restore with .dump format. So we should somehow make the folder format work.

Do you have any idea on why this error is showing up  and how to troubleshoot ?

I tried pg_dump command with folder format. Expected the command to finish successfully and generate the dump in folder. But it failed.

Comment: Those are some huge directories.  How many files do they contain?  Maybe you are exceeding some limit on how many files can be in a single directory.

Comment: pg_dump is presumably just passing on the error it got from the system.  So what is your system?  OS, docker version, volume definition, etc.

Comment: Updated the VM Specifications, Docker version and volume definitions in the description.